# Batch requests and concurrent processing

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I have a service in NodeJS which fetches user details from DB and sends that to another application via http. There can be millions of user records, so processing this 1 by 1 is very slow. I have implemented concurrent processing for this like this:

```
const userIds = [1,2,3....];
const users$ = from(this.getUsersFromDB(userIds));
const concurrency = 150;

users$.pipe(
    switchMap((users) =>
        from(users).pipe(
            mergeMap((user) => from(this.publishUser(user)), concurrency),
            toArray()
        )
    )
).subscribe(
    (partialResults: any) => {
        // Do something with partial results.
    },
    (err: any) => {
        // Error
    },
    () => {
        // done.
    }
);
```

This works perfectly fine for thousands of user records, it's processing 150 user records concurrently at a time, pretty faster than publishing users 1 by 1.

But problem occurs when processing millions of user records, getting those from database is pretty slow as result set size also goes to GBs(more memory usage also).
I am looking for a solution to get user records from DB in batches, while keep on publishing those records concurrently in parallel.

I thinking of a solution like, maintain a queue(of size N) of user records fetched from DB, whenever queue size is less than N, fetch next N results from DB and add to this queue.
Then the current solution which I have, will keep on getting records from this queue and keep on processing those concurrently with defined concurrency. But I am not quite able to put this in code. Is there are way we can do this using RxJS?

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution is the right one, i.e. using the concurrent parameter of `mergeMap`.

The point that I do not understand is why you are adding `toArray` at the end of the pipe.

`toArray` buffers all the notifications coming from upstream and will emit only when the upstream `complete`s.

This means that, in your case, the `subscribe` does not process partial results but processes all of the results you have obtained executing `publishUser` for all users.

On the contrary, if you remove `toArray` and leave `mergeMap` with its concurrent parameter, what you will see is a continuous flow of results into the `subscribe` due to the concurrency of the process.

This is for what `rxjs` is concerned. Then you can look at the specific DB you are using to see if it supports batch reads. In which case you can create buffers of user ids with the `bufferCount` operator and query the db with such buffers.